# iOS transitions become instantaneous

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, transition

I'm developing a basic iOS app that doesn't use any fancy animations except for the built in transitions between views. After testing the app on both the simulator and an iPhone 4S for a while, the animations suddenly become instantaneous. For example, clicking the back button makes the previous view appear instantly instead of sliding back in.

I don't get any errors, and I don't call setAnimationsEnabled at any point. The app remains fully functional except for the lack of animations.

**EDIT:** Occasionally, the tab bar items also disappear. This doesn't always happen, but the disappearing only happens when the animations stop working so I'm guessing they're somehow related.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is incorrect use of threads. Are you using multi-threading of Grand Central Dispatch? If so and you attempt to perform UI animations from threads other than the main thread, all sorts of nasty UI thing happen. Animations and related UI manipulation should only happen on the main thread.

Comment: Yes! This was it. I moved everything to the main thread and the problem seems to have gone away. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking for memory leaks and generally keeping an eye on memory usage. I've never seen the symptom you describe, but it sounds like the sort of thing that might occur when memory starts to get tight. The best way to get a good understanding of your app's memory use is to profile the app in Instruments.